# Android display a ProgressDialog on a ListActivity when using multiple external AsynTasks

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-dialog

So I am completely new to Andorid programming and can't seem to get a ProgressDialog to show on a ListActivity (ScheduleActiviy in my example) when running an AsyncTask from a separate class (GetGames in my example).  I am attempting to use separate class for code re-usability.  When I previously had the AsyncTask as an embedded class it seemed to work.  I have posted what I believe to be all the relevant code. Any help would be great.  Thanks!

ScheduleActivity.java

```
public class ScheduleActivity extends ListActivity 
{   
     private final String PDIALOG_MSG = "Loading schedule...";

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
     {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.schedule);

          ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> gamesList = null;

          try 
          {
               // Loading information in Background Threads
               gamesList = new GetGames(ScheduleActivity.this, PDIALOG_MSG).execute().get();
```

GetGames.java

```
public class GetGames extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> 
{   
     private Context context;
     private ProgressDialog pDialog;
     private String pDialogMsg;

     public GetGames(Context ctx, String dialogMsg)
     {
          context = ctx;
          pDialogMsg = dialogMsg;
     }

     @Override
     public void onPreExecute()
     {
          super.onPreExecute();
          pDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
          pDialog.setMessage(pDialogMsg);
          pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
          pDialog.setCancelable(false);
          pDialog.show();
     }

     @Override
     public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> rtnList)
     {
          pDialog.dismiss();
     }
```

Comment: Your directly waiting for the result from the async task class like get(); Use interfaces as listener or the receivers, and just call execute, this will perform onPreExecute() method and than starts doinbackground() tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Your ProgressDialog should probably be controlled on the Activity level instead of the AsyncTask level. Theoretically I don't see why how you're doing it wouldn't work, but I can show you a method which definitely works (it's what I do) and it organizes things a bit differently:

```
//In AsyncTask

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    showProgressDialog(R.string.importing_pages);
}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(Boolean b) {
    hideProgressDialog();
}

//In Activity

public void showProgressDialog(int msgResId) {
    showProgressDialog(getString(msgResId));
}

public void showProgressDialog(String msg) {
    mProgressDialog = ProgressDialogHelper.buildDialog(this, msg);
    mProgressDialog.show();
}

public void hideProgressDialog() {
    if(mProgressDialog != null)
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
}

//My progress dialog helper class:

public class ProgressDialogHelper {

    /**
     * Creates a generic progress dialog with the specified message
     *
     * @param activity the activity which hosts the dialog. This must be an activity, not a context.
     * @param msgResId the resId for the message to display
     * @return a progress dialog
     */
    public static ProgressDialog buildDialog(Activity activity, int msgResId) {
        return buildDialog(activity, activity.getApplicationContext().getString(msgResId));
    }

    /**
     * Creates a generic progress dialog with the specified message
     *
     * @param activity the activity which hosts the dialog. This must be an activity, not a context.
     * @param msg the message to display
     * @return a progress dialog
     */
    public static ProgressDialog buildDialog(Activity activity, String msg) {
        ProgressDialog dialog;

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(new ContextThemeWrapper(activity, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Dialog));
        else
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);

        dialog.setMessage(msg);
        dialog.setCancelable(false);

        return dialog;
    }

}
```

You don't have to make a helper class if you don't want to, it's just how I organized it. The main idea here is that the progress dialog should be owned by the Activity instead of the AsyncTask.

Also, the context used must be the **activity's**, not `getApplicationContext()`. It looks like you have that part right though.

Answer (score 0):

You can display Progress Dialogs using AsyncTasks. That's not a problem. I do it all the time.  What may be the problem is the doInBackground() method. What do you have there?

I also generally nest the AsyncTasks within the Activity class, so that it can call other Activity class methods in the onPostExecute() method. Otherwise, in order for it to communicate back with your Activity you'll have to use something like a handler or static references.

```
public class TestActivity extends Activity {

    private AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> bgLoader;
    private ArrayList<String> listOfStuff;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);

        listOfStuff = new ArrayList<String>();
        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        textView.setText("Your list has " + listOfStuff.size() + " items in it!");
        bgLoader = new MyAsyncTask(this, "Waiting...").execute();

    }

    private void resumeDoingStuff() {
        try {
            listOfStuff = bgLoader.get();
            textView.setText("Your list has " + listOfStuff.size() + " items in it!");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

        private ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        private String message;
        private Context ctx;

        public MyAsyncTask(Context context, String message) {
            this.ctx = context;
            this.message = message;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ctx);
            progressDialog.setMessage(message);
            progressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            progressDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {

            ArrayList<String> retList = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                try {
                    retList.add("TEST STRING " + i);
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            return retList;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> result) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            resumeDoingStuff();
        }

    }

}
```

[image: With Progress]

[image: After Progress Dismissal]